# How to define the "Light, Normal, Bold" versions of a font-family in Document Service?

Tags: google-apps-script

This doesn't work:

```
body.insertParagraph(2,"Hello");
title_style = {};
title_style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Roboto Condensed Light';
body.getChild(2).setAttributes(title_style);
```

Whereas the `normal` version of the font does:

```
body.insertParagraph(2,"Hello");
title_style = {};
title_style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Roboto Condensed';
body.getChild(2).setAttributes(title_style);
```

Where they exist, how can I define that a `Light` version of a `font-family` be used?

Comment: the `FONT_FAMILY` Enum is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/font-family). Use `.setFontFamily()` instead and see if that takes care of the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work:  `var my_paragraph = body.insertParagraph(3,"My Paragraph Text");  my_paragraph.setFontFamily('Roboto Condensed Light')`.  I need to find what convention/syntax is required to define the `Light` version of the font - using `setFontFamily('Roboto Condensed')` works fine, but that is not the light version of the font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading and playing some more, my guess is that Google is differentiating between the *family* of fonts (Roboto Condensed) and the *weight* of the fonts (Light, Normal, Bold). As of right now, there is no way to set the weight of the font through GAS in Documents.

Comment: Pity, seems Google Sheets has a [setFontWeight()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontweightfontweight) method, just need to be able to define values other than `bold` or `normal`, eg `300` to get the `light` effect.

Answer (score 3):

Just had to figure this out myself as there are no answers anywhere else. You have to add ";300" to the font family declaration in your style attribute object. So, for example:

let subtitleStyle = {};
subtitleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = data.styleFontFamily + ";300";

Comment: This worked. It should be the correct answer.